# os.rename() works on open files in Mac. what is the alternative?

Tags: python, macos

I needed a mechanism in Python using which I could detect whether a file is open by some other application or not. For Windows, a solution which worked for me was trying to rename the file. Windows doesn't allow you to rename a file if its still open by some other application.

Unfortunately this didn't work on a Mac. Mac OS X allows you to rename a file while it is open by some other application. It seems to be a useful feature purposely built into the system (see “[Rename open files](http://www.macworld.com/article/141993/2009/07/filerename.html)”).

What could be an alternative solution for Mac OS X so that I could figure out whether any application is holding a file or not?

Comment: Just FYI, when you’re talking about an Apple-branded computer, it’s Mac, not MAC. MAC is an acronym meaning [Media Access Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address).

Comment: Sorry about that Jeff. Will take care going forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `os.open` with `O_EXLOCK` flag.

This might be not a general solution, but it should work on Unix like systems, including Mac.

Comment: It only works on BSD derivatives -- for example it's not available on Linux.

Comment: Yeah, on Linux you need to run `open` and after that `flock`.

Comment: I don't know what `O_EXLOCK` does, but `flock` will only ensure there is no other process holding a lock at the same time.  It does not ensure there is no other process holding an open file handle.

Answer (score 0):

There is no general solution to this problem.  If you have control over the other applications using the file, you can use some kind of lock files.  But if you just want to know if *any* applpication has an open file handle to some file, there is no platform independent solution -- whether in Python or in any other language.

Comment: If something Mac specific can be given, that would be good. I need to run this program only on Windows and Mac.